# Using proxies with python requests

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I am writing a crawler using multiple proxies, basically (I have a pool of verified proxies) in a single process, I start 30 threads, each random picks one of the proxies and use it to fetch some url and I set the timeout of each request to 30 seconds. 
However, after running for a while, I got the error of opening too many files, I guess there are some connections not closed? 
And if I don't use proxy with same number of threads, there are no such error. 
Could someone help?

### Code:

code starting threads:

```
    ...
    # the queue of url for request 
    queue.add_url(url)
    for i in range(numOfThreads):
        x = crawlerThread(...)
        threadList.append(x)
        x.start()
        time.sleep(30)
    ...
```

code in crawling:

```
    while currentUrl:
        # different sessions use different ip of the servers 
        sessionId = (sessionId+1) % len(self.sessions)
        try:
            session, proxy = self.random_use_ip_session_proxy(sessionId)
            if proxy:
                # if proxy is not None, use proxy, otherwise use my own ip, returned proxy is list of two elements, 
                # the first one is proxy, second one is for counting 
                response = session.get(currentUrl, timeout=60, verify=False, proxies=proxy[0])
            else:
                response = session.get(currentUrl, timeout=60, verify=False)

        except Exception as e:
            # some error handling 

        ... # analyze the code and produce more url
```

### Edit:

Now the program won't report too many open file error (I am still seeing the number of socket connects grow rapidly till 10000), but suddenly it just stopped with no error, is it possible somehow it is killed by kernel? Where can I check this?

Comment: Too many files open would lead me to believe when crawling the pages you are writing the results to a file and those aren't being closed. I would suggest adding a snippet of your code to help clarify the issue.

Comment: I am not writing anything to disk, just fetching and analyzing, let me simplify the code and paste it.

Comment: Pinpoint the problem now, it is because of phantomJS, the part of code is not written by me, I have corrected that. It should not happen now. How can I close this question?

Comment: You could add an answer stating it was an issue with phantomJS and then accept it as the answer.

Comment: Wmm, phantomJS's problem has been solved, but still same error, guess still something wrong with requests module.

Comment: I know you've seen the [requests thread](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/239) talking about this issue, are you closing the response each time with `response.close()`?

Comment: I didn't close that, because I did try that, but it seems after close, the response is still readable.

Comment: Oh, do you mean response.close() will close the connection, but content will not be deleted?

Comment: You should be able to get the information from the response object still, or you could call it after you processed the information within the response.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It should close the connection and you should be able to still use the information.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's much better now.

Comment: That is good to hear, be sure to add an answer stating the issue was resolved by using `response.close()` to ensure the connections are closed.

Comment: Sure, I will add the answer after I finish testing very soon, actually the other problem is using proxy won't give me a higher throughput, do you know why? Or how to debug that? The situation is: previously I use two threads without proxy to crawling, now I use 30 threads with proxies for crawling, but I don't see any increase in speed, but I neither hit the limit of CPU/RAM/Disk, nor bandwidth limit. Also I only choose the proxy respond within 3 seconds (throw away the slow ones).  @CoryShay

Comment: Have you verified that the proxy is in fact being used, by testing the connection against something like [whatismyip.com](https://www.whatismyip.com/)? It is possible depending on the number of proxies you are using that the site(s) you are connecting against is throttling your connections. Usually there will be a little bit of overhead when using proxies also since they may also be throttling connections and there is an extra hop+.

Comment: Yes, I randomly test the proxy, it is working as far as I know, and I guess 30 threads are not many enough to have a large website to reach its bottleneck. In my situation, I have over 200 proxies and 30 threads, each randomly pick one proxy or use my own ip to access the target, after getting the webpage, it saves some content into a tree, the structure is protected by a lock from simultaneously updating. I just can't figure out why using 30 threads is even slower than using 2 threads without proxies. What are the possible reasons besides slow proxy? And how can I debug that? @CoryShay

Comment: Since you said you save the information into a tree that has a lock around it, when you increase the # of threads, it is entirely possible that is your bottleneck. Since you have 30 threads trying to get access to the object they all have to wait while another one modifies it. You may be better off having them all put the information into a queue and a finishing thread place them into your tree structure. So only one thread has to access the tree structure, and each thread has it's own queue to append information to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106766/discussion-between-cory-shay-and-1a1a11a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as Cory Shay mentioned in the comment, response.close() will close the connection, but the content of response is still available.